# How to establish a condition to show another view if the first view has no results?

Tags: views, 7

I have some blocks with views that show upcoming events of different categories. Now, if one category has no results, how can i trigger another views-block with another category (that is normally not displayed)? I was trying to get this done with the context-module, but i have only the possibilty to create a context IF a view is shown...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write a php code, in your view UI, in the textarea for behavior when no result :

```
print views_embed_view( 'your_other_view_name', 'default');
```

NB : enable PHP filter module